# test .net core 2 page using Postman return 400 bad request

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-2.0

I created default project template of .net core 2 pages , than I'm trying to test a call to a page OnPostAsync (not api controller) using postman ,
but I always get 400 bad request  , tried to play with headers etc` but with no success , any 1 manage to do this?
After this will work ,my goal is to do do end-to-end/load tests

thanks!

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

answer was found https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7012 which it's a workaround to disable `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` using     [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)] on PageModel

[image]