# What is the "url" to ajax-call a C# function in an asp.net core razor pages application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, razor-pages

In the auto-generated site.js file of the ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project in Visual Studio, I am trying to call with Ajax

```
    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: "asdsad",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (status, ex) {
                alert("Error Code: Status: " + status + " Ex: " + ex);
            }
        });
```

a C# function. My project tree looks like this:

[image: ASP.NET Core Razor Pages project tree]

The `builder.cshtml.cs` file was also auto-generated by Visual Studio when I added the `builder.cshtml` page. Inside my `builder.cshtml.cs` there is this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace MyProjectName.Pages
{
    public class Index1Model : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; } = "Initial Request";
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "Test1";
        }

        public void HelloFunc()
        {
            Message = "BuilderJob";
        }
    }
}
```

I added the function `HelloFunc()` and the `Message` variable. I don't understand after going through the [ASP.NET Core documentation by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows) what is the "url" to call the `HelloFunc` from my Ajax code. It is not `/builder/HelloFunc` (doesn't work). How do I access this `HelloFunc` from my Ajax call?

The answer is to change `HelloFunc` to `OnPostHelloFunc()` and use this `url: /builder?handler=HelloFunc` and if you are just testing and not using a validation token, to insert [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)] as instructed here [test .net core 2 page using Postman return 400 bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453401/test-net-core-2-page-using-postman-return-400-bad-request)

Comment: void methods dosen't have return

Comment: was due to old code, removed it from the question

Comment: take a look at [this demo](http://demo.ziyad.info/MultipleSubmit/MultipleSubmit) for multiple submit buttons. there is two samples, first with standard forms, and the second using ajax which I think will help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example AJAX call back to an ASP.NET Core Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410716/example-ajax-call-back-to-an-asp-net-core-razor-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor Pages is using page handlers for this. So if you want to POST to your page, create a method with the name `OnPost{HandlerName}` or `OnPost{HandlerName}Async`, if its an async method.

As an exmaple, if you have a form and want to delete something, You'd need a page handler like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int id)
{
    var itemToDelete = await _mapRepo.GetByIdAsync(id);
    if (itemToDelete == null)
    {
        //...
    }

    await _mapRepo.Delete(itemToDelete);
    return RedirectToPage("Maps");
}
```

The `OnPost` declares, that asp.net core will listen for a POST request, `Delete` is the name, while `Async` is a naming convention for async handlers.

In your form, you would then simply declare an input element, that would call this handler during the onclick event:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Delete</button>
```

Doing this with ajax:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/builder?handler=HelloFunc",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (status, ex) {
        alert("Error Code: Status: " + status + " Ex: " + ex);
    }
});
```

With a handler method:

```
public void OnPostHelloFunc()
{
    //...
}
```

Here is a good read on named handlers: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

Comment: I don't want to do this with a form because It's really complicated to prevent a page refresh. However, using the url "/builder?handler=HelloFunc" and changing the function to `OnPostHelloFunc`, I get `XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: https://localhost:44388/builder?handler=HelloFunc
Line Number 1, Column 1:` in the console of firefox. Also the alert of the error function is being thrown and it says `Error Code: Status: [object Object] Ex: error`

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the Hellofunc method, and see if it is being hit. If so, thi is most likely an error with your ajax method expecting an xml response, but not receiving one. After all a void method does not return anything. You really should return an `IActionResult`

Comment: I changed the `OnPostHelloFunc` type to `IActionResult` and I am returning `Content("BuilderJob")`. In the first line of the function (which is `Message = "BuilderJob")` I set a breakpoint. The breakpoint is not being hit. I am using this `url` in the ajax call: `url: "/builder?handler=HelloFunc"`. The javascript error is the same in the console of firefox as well as in the alert

Comment: If I change the function to `OnGetHelloFunc` and I do a `GET` ajax call with all the other parameters the same it works (breakpoint gets hit, result is success), why?

Comment: Apparently it's because it's expecting a token to validate. For testing you can disable it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453401/test-net-core-2-page-using-postman-return-400-bad-request

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.2), Here they have mentioned file name and path map with its matching url.

For exa.

/Pages/Index.cshtml   => / or /Index

/Pages/Contact.cshtml  => /Contact

Another thing is Razor Pages follow particular naming convention. It prefixed with "**On**" followed by HTTP Verb like `OnGet()`, `OnPost()` etc. However, we can also specify custom names. For example -

- OnGetPatientList()
- OnPostHelloFunc()

Now if we talk about your case then you need to do the following change in your `builder.cshtml.cs` file.

```
namespace MyProjectName.Pages
{
    public class Index1Model : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; } = "Initial Request";
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message = "Test1";
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostHelloFunc()
        {
            return Content("BuilderJob");
        }
    }
}
```

and your ajax function look like this -

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/builder?handler=HelloFunc",
    dataType: "text",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (status, ex) {
        alert("Error Code: Status: " + status + " Ex: " + ex);
    }
});
```

Comment: Although this doesn't answer how to access HelloFunc() (is it not possible/right?), I want to ask, why did you set the type of the function to IActionResult? It does not compile: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'`

Comment: @Tasos: I have modified my answer with some more explanation.